# How do i get tweets from a specified user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to extract tweets from a particular user based on a specific keyword but ran into some difficulties. I got the error: 'user' object is not iterable.

```
#Import the libraries 
import tweepy 
from textblob import TextBlob 
from wordcloud import WordCloud 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 
import sys 
import csv 
import string 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

api_key = "JISLFz4iz1WRyG1sPtg6Iuhob"
api_key_secret = ""
access_token = "1372812318900252672-fVqTH8B6TvrexgYyrSF4gSu1oF4SEl"
access_token_secret = ""

auth_handler = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_key_secret)
auth_handler.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth_handler,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user = api.get_user("NewtoCryto")

print("User details:")
print(user.name)
print(user.description)

for tweets in user:
  for tweet in api.search(q="defi", lang="en", rpp=10):
    print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
```

Comment: read the docs, `get_user` doesnt return the users tweets, so there is nothing to iterate.https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user, maybe you want `user_timeline` https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline

Comment: hmm yeah.  The API.user _timeline shows this:Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the authenticating user or the user specified. It’s also possible to request another user’s timeline via the id parameter.

Comment: im not sure if i can extract the tweet out

Comment: maybe check out https://fairyonice.github.io/extract-someones-tweet-using-tweepy.html, you could just loop over all the users tweets then search the text in each tweet for what your looking for

Comment: Thanks man, taking a look.. but the thing is I am looking for something more targeted to a particular user. Maybe twitter’s privacy policy is restrictive.

Comment: user_timeline targets specific user..........you just pass the user id you want to serach

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thank you for referring me to the github. It works!